# How to change api address after compilation in Angular2/Angular4

Tags: javascript, angular

I am working on Angular 4 project using CLI 1.4.4
I have kept my api URL address in separate file as js file in assets. I have exported and imported that address in my code. API address may change in future, so i wanted to change that address so i kept it as separate Js file.

I have compiled my code. when i wanted to change api URL its not changing in compiled code.

I would like to know is it possible to change URL address after compilation or not? If it can be changed can you suggest me some methods

Thanks

Comment: and what solution did you come up with?

Comment: instead of declaring the API endpoint as const, declare it as variable (let) and write if else conditions depending on your logic.

Comment: right but need a little more explanatory code...